# Keep row name as an id with dplyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I've got this data with 20848 entries:

```
    V1           V2            V3           V4           V5           V6           V7           V8           V9           V10          V11          V12
1   0.023255814  0.1000000000  0.046511628  0.004651163  0.030232558  0.000000000  0.369767442  0.020930233  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.025581395  0.379069767
2   0.063750000  0.0112500000  0.001250000  0.105000000  0.120000000  0.522500000  0.005000000  0.000000000  0.005000000  0.002500000  0.163750000  0.000000000
3   0.026605505  0.3844036697  0.192660550  0.017431193  0.000000000  0.004587156  0.013761468  0.028440367  0.163302752  0.097247706  0.014678899  0.056880734
...
```

I am using 'tidyr' library in R to get the top 3 V# numbers from each row like this:

```
gather(as.data.frame(matrix), key = "Name", value = "Prob",factor_key = TRUE) %>% 
                                   group_by(Name) %>% 
                                   top_n(n = 3)
```

Getting this outcome:

```
   Name   Prob
   <fct> <dbl>
 1 V1    0.717
 2 V1    0.682
 3 V1    0.686
 4 V2    0.756
 5 V2    0.767
 6 V2    0.817
 7 V3    0.806
 8 V3    0.871
 9 V3    0.801
10 V4    0.779
# ... with 26 more rows
```

But I need to keep the row number as an id to match other info from another dataset that is following the same structure.
What I mean is that I want to get an outcome like this:

```
   Name   Prob    row
   <fct> <dbl>
 1 V1    0.717    4151
 2 V1    0.682    17
 3 V1    0.686    3215
 4 V2    0.756    17565
 5 V2    0.767    13254
 6 V2    0.817    3
 7 V3    0.806    2135
 8 V3    0.871    298
 9 V3    0.801    4568
10 V4    0.779    542
# ... with 26 more rows
```

I know it might be a little basic, but someone could please be able to help?

Comment: you can use `tibble::rownames_to_column()` before transforming your data to the long format (but you need to transform your matrix to a data frame first as the function will only work on a data frame)

Comment: Note that using `matrix` for the name of your matrix is not a great practice because it is the name of a function

Comment: Yes indeed, I just wanted to keep it sample by keeping complex names for myself but still having it easy going for those who kindly read my question. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using `m` instead of `matrix` as the name of your matrix since "matrix" is the name of a function in R.

Also, `pivot_longer()` replaced `gather()` in `tidyr`.

You can use `tibble::rownames_to_column()` before transforming your data to the long format (but you need to transform your matrix to a data frame first as the function will only work on a data frame):

```
m <- as.data.frame(m)

m %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "Row") %>%
  pivot_longer(-Row, names_to = "Name", values_to = "Prob") %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  top_n(n = 3) %>%
  select(c(2, 3, 1))
```

Output:

```
   Name     Prob Row  
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
 1 V1    0.0233  1    
 2 V2    0.1     1    
 3 V3    0.0465  1    
 4 V4    0.00465 1    
 5 V5    0.0302  1    
 6 V6    0       1    
 7 V7    0.370   1    
 8 V8    0.0209  1    
 9 V9    0       1    
10 V10   0       1    
# … with 26 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

mat <- matrix(sample(1:24), nrow = 6, ncol = 4, 
              dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:4]))

mat

#>       A  B  C  D
#> [1,] 11 20  1  3
#> [2,] 16  2 14 18
#> [3,] 13  6  4 23
#> [4,]  5 19  7 15
#> [5,] 10 17 12 22
#> [6,]  9 21 24  8
```

Give the matrix the row number as row names (I use `magrittr::set_rownames()` so that I can do it in a pipeline), then use `as_tibble()` to preserve rownames reliably.

```r
mat %>% 
    set_rownames(seq_len(nrow(.))) %>% 
    as_tibble(rownames = "row") %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -row, names_to = "Name", values_to = "Prob") %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    top_n(3, Prob) %>% 
    arrange(Name)

#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   Name [4]
#>    row   Name   Prob
#>    <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 1     A        11
#>  2 2     A        16
#>  3 3     A        13
#>  4 1     B        20
#>  5 4     B        19
#>  6 6     B        21
#>  7 2     C        14
#>  8 5     C        12
#>  9 6     C        24
#> 10 2     D        18
#> 11 3     D        23
#> 12 5     D        22
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I want to do, but it seems the new way to do it is `rowid_to_column()` coming after `as.tibble()` instead of `set_rownames(seq_len(nrow(.)))`